# Mongoose, pushing an object into an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have this Schema:

```
{
    _id: 12345,
    name: 'Just a name'
    object: {
         arrayOfObjects: [{ number: 1}, { number: 2} ]
    }
}
```

How can i push an object into the `arrayOfObjects`?
I'd tried with this:

```
    await Model.updateOne({ _id: 12345 }, {
         object: { $push: { arrayOfObjects: { number: 3 }}
    }
```

And i didn't work...

Comment: $push is in the wrong place. Try `{ $push: { "object.arrayOfObjects": { number: 3 }}}`.

Comment: You hit on the spot... i have to change a little things, but it works... Thank you